# Double-click beavior on a TreeNode checkbox

Tags: c#, treeview, checkbox, double-click, treenode

I have a `TreeView` populated with `TreeNodes` having icons and checkboxes.

I've been tryig to disable the checkig/unchecking ability of some of them discarding the event in the `BerforeCheck` method. This works fine, until I double click on the checkbox: the image of the checkbox is the opposite of its real state (it shows a check mark if the status is `Checked=false`). I've tried to fix that changing the StateImageIndex manually in the `NodeDoubleClick` and `BeforeClick` method with no success.

Even worse: I added a third image in the `StateImageList` (yes I want the checkboxes to be tri-state too) but I'm not using it yet (it's never set in my code), and the third image is set as the current state of the box after some double-click (at this point I can't determine a clear behavior).

How can I do to at best make it work as exepected, at worst disable the double-click on the checkbox?
Thanks.

PS: The question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643630/phantom-second-click-for-winforms-treeview-checkbox), but had no answer...

Comment: I tested it and basically when you double-click a checkbox the check-change is detected only once. What's exactly the problem ? Can you post some code ?

Comment: P.S. I'm using XP at the moment, perhaps it's a vista/seven problem only...

Comment: The problem is that after a double click the image of the checkbox changes twice (as for two clicks) while the state of the checkbox changes only once => incoherent behavior. Besides there's not much code to show, it's basically the default behavior of the component...  BTW I'm using Vista.

Comment: When I double-click a node's checkbox, the image (with "image" I mean the checkbox flag) and the node checked-state change both only once, so I can't reproduce the problem... perhaps it's OK on XP :(

Comment: Yes, I confirm it, it works fine on XP while in Win 7 I have the same problem as you...

Comment: It may be related to the .NET framework shipped with the OS... do you know which one you used for your tests?

Comment: I used .net 3.5. Anyway, the problem is definitely on the OS because I used the same executable on both OS and on xp was OK while on W7 the issue appeared...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.. :) worked for me

```
public class NewTreeView : TreeView
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == 0x203)
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
            else
                base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```